# Cannot open file, path = 'assets/responseFile' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to write on the existing txt file that was stored in a assets in android Studio. But, it throws error

```
assets:
  - assets/responseFile.txt
```

here is my code:

```
String content =  response.body.toString();
String path = "assets/responseFile.txt";
var file = new File(path);
file.writeAsString(content);
```

I have also tried this way. But no luck

```
writingFile(String content) async {
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String filePath = '${appDocDir.path}/assets/responseFile.txt';
  new File(filePath).writeAsString(content);}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your pubspec.yaml is wrong. It should be:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/responseFile.txt #This in case the file is stored in the "assets" folder on the root of your Flutter project.
```

Also you must be sure to respect the identation.

Comment: The pubspec.yaml was actually as you stated. I edited it. I have still got the error

Comment: I have the same issue.